# open another android app using Ionic2

Tags: android, ionic2

I have created an Unity game. I have also created an Ionic2 app on Android. Both are installed on my Android Marshmallow.

I Ionic2 app I use AppAvailability plugin to detect if unity game is installed or not & give true.

Now I want that in my Ionic2 app, have a button on which click to open the Unity game app.

My **Unity2 app** have intent like this.

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:host="scan" android:path="/" android:scheme="deelink" />
        </intent-filter>
```

And in my **Ionic2 app** I try

```
AppAvailability.check(this.appName)
  .then(
    (yes: boolean) => {
      console.log(this.appName + ' is available');
      this.isAppAvailable = true;
      window.open('deelink://', '_system', 'location=no');
    },
    (no: string) => console.log(this.appName + ' is NOT available')
  );
```

But the window.open give error.

Can anyone plz guide me how to call another app on button click in Ionic2.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using `inAppBrowser` plugin too?

Comment: yes, I have installed InAppBrowser plugin